# Import csv data into SQL Server Express

Tags: database, csv

I am developing an asp.net mvc application. I have a very large data set in a CSV file that I want to import into a SQL Server Express database.

What is the simplest way to go about this task? Ideally I just want to import the data and the table will be created automatically with the columns defined and the data.

Comment: IF you have a full version of SQL Server Management Studio somewhere - just connect to your Express instance, find your database in the Object Explorer, right-click on it, select `Tasks > Import Data` and follow that wizard through - it allows you to map columns, skip rows, rename columns - whatever you dream of. At the end - run the package, and your data is loaded into your SQL Server table.

Comment: retag-remove MVC, this question has nothing to do with MVC. Marc gives the right answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655380/import-csv-into-sql-server-including-automatic-table-creation ?

Answer (score 3):

Marc is right, just download [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22985) 
and import the data

Comment: I'm on Debian 11 so SSMS will not work for me. Also, the Import Flat File Wizard for Visual Studio Code is hanging without an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I figured out a way to do this by accident. From a 2008 R2 full version of SQL I created a script from a Database table by using the script wizzard and scripting the data with the script.  All you would need to do is add a few columns to your spreadsheet like insert table name etc.. all this wizard does is create a CSV type file using commas and N for the escape character.  see example here.  hope this helps someone... BTW save it as a .sql file and open it in a query window and execute it!

```
USE [databaseName]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DrNames]    Script Date: 02/06/2014 22:44:44 ******/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DrNames] ON
INSERT [dbo].[DrNames] ([ID], [DrName], [PreFix], [EmailAddress]) VALUES (1, N'test1 Dr Name', N'Psy.D.', N'TestDrNAme1@DrPlace.com')
INSERT [dbo].[DrNames] ([ID], [DrName], [PreFix], [EmailAddress]) VALUES (2, N'test2 Dr Name', N'Psy.D.', N'TestDrNAme2@DrPlace.com')
INSERT [dbo].[DrNames] ([ID], [DrName], [PreFix], [EmailAddress]) VALUES (3, N'test3 Dr Name', N'Ph.D.', N'TestDrNAme3@DrPlace.com')
INSERT [dbo].[DrNames] ([ID], [DrName], [PreFix], [EmailAddress]) VALUES (4, N'test4 Dr Name', N'MD', N'TestDrNAme4@DrPlace.com')
```