# Update or insert from csv into sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a CSV file containing user info, say

```
first_name;last_name;user_id;full_name
```

column separator is `;`, row terminator is `\n`.

What I need to do is to insert or update into `users` table. Unique key is `user_id`: if record with this `user_id` already exists, I need to update, if it doesn't I need to insert.

However, there are some problems that prevent me from using management studio data-import or `bulk insert`.

First, there are more fields in the `users` table (not just 4) and the order of columns in `csv` file does not correspond to the order of columns in the table. So I need to be able to specify which column from the file goes to which column in the table.

Secondly, some additional fields need to be filled. For example, `users.email = users.user_id`. Here is another obstacle - though for a newly inserted row `users.email = users.user_id` it is possible that `users.email` will change in the future, so I cannot just insert `user_id` and then run `update [users] set [email] = [user_id]`.

Comment: have you tried using the import data wizard? sounds like you may need a two stage process

Comment: One thing you can do is import all the data to a temporary table and `insert/update` to your target table using new temporary table. Also have a look at [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper) articles

Comment: @Yakyb in import data wizard I cannot fill additional fields. Or can I?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, can I use `#temp` table here? `bulk insert` into it from csv, then write a script like `if exists(... where user_id=...) then (update ...) else (insert ... )` and then `#drop temp`. Is that correct?

Comment: @xaxa: Sorry I mean not a `#temp`. Physical table in the database to use temporary for this import. Which can be deleted after!

Comment: @xaxa: But I think. you can try this way [How to create and populate a table in a single step as part of a CSV import operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper).

Answer (score 0):

Use fgetcsv

Example with two colonne :

```
<?php
$row = 0;
$update = "";
//separator of column
$separator = ";";

//creates two variables containing the index columns to read / modify
$idx_nom = 0;
$idx_rubrique = 1;

//Open file writing
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{

   //we travel the file line by line, storing the data in a table
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
    {
       //can not control that the second line if the first contains the column headers
       if ($row != 0)
       {
          //conditions of one column 
          if (stristr($data[$idx_nom], 'chemise'))
          {
             $data[$idx_rubrique] = 1;
          }
           else if (stristr($data[$idx_nom], 'costume'))
          {
             $data[$idx_rubrique] = 2;
          }
           else if (stristr($data[$idx_nom], 'cravate'))
          {
             $data[$idx_rubrique] = 3;
          }
      }

      $update   .= implode($separator,$data)."\r\n";
      $row++;
   }

    fclose($handle);
}

//update from csv
$ouvre=fopen("test.csv","w+");
fwrite($ouvre,$update);
fclose($ouvre);
?>
```