# Insert into SQL from CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

I have the following CSV File:

```
AFRICA,Zimbabwe,7,Telecel Zimbabwe,1,0,1,0,0,1
AFRICA,Zambia,7,Celtel Zambia Plc,1,0,1,0,0,1
```

I am using the following query but for some reason it's giving an error:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'pathtofile' INTO TABLE databasename.tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It is giving a data truncated warning and not importing anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and populate a table in a single step as part of a CSV import operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper)

Comment: You give `ENCLOSED BY '"'` but I see no single `"`

Comment: If only some of the CSV file uses `"`, then change `ENCLOSED BY` to `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to ensure that the receiving data fields are in the correct order and are of the correct type and size.

Then you specify `ENCLOSED BY '"'`, but your example data is *not* actually enclosed...

Answer (score 0):

Check The Query in database :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...)
```