# Importing a CSV file into VS 2015 Database

Tags: sql-server, csv, visual-studio-2015

I have a SQL Server Database as a project. I created it using Add Item -> SQL Server.

On the database project I do Add Item > Table which adds an SQL file. That sql file just creates a table with column Id, nothing else.

I then published that database. I can now see it on the Server Object Explorer.
I want to populate the table using a CSV file, and I also want to import the columns from the CSV file.

Then I created a new Query in the Object Explorer and used a BULK INSERT statement to import the csv file. I wanted to see if it would work because the table has just an Id column, and it did not. So my question is, how do I import the new columns when the table already has it's own schema?

I have also used the SQL Import and Export Wizard which is packaged with Microsoft SQL Server 2016. That is able to create a new table, but not import the new columns into a previously existing table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create and populate a table in a single step as part of a CSV import operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper)

Comment: You need to use some DDL before adding the data to the table, which means you need to create the columns that don't exist, then import the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the explanation of how to do this in 1 operation here:

[How to create and populate a table in a single step as part of a CSV import operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418461/how-to-create-and-populate-a-table-in-a-single-step-as-part-of-a-csv-import-oper)